# Lucene Synonym Filter behavior

Tags: lucene, synonym

I am trying to figure out how does lucene's analyzer work?
My question is how does lucene handle synonym words? Here is the situation:
we have single words and multi words

single: foo = bar
multi words: foo bar =  foobar

For single words:

- Does lucene expand the indexed records or not? I guess if a query has a word like "foo", it adds "bar" to the query too. I don't know if it happens for indexing or not?

For multi words:

- Does lucene expand both query and indexing? for example if we have "foo bar", does it add foobar to the indexing/query?

My second question is : Lucene uses a stream of tokens and gives them to the filters like lowercase filter. My question is how does lucene find the multi words? like how does it find out that "foo bar" is a multi words that are together?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

[SynonymFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) can, optionally, keep the original word, and add the synonym to the tokenstream as well, by setting `keepOrig`=true (see [SynonymMap.Builder.add()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymMap.Builder.html#add%28org.apache.lucene.util.CharsRef,%20org.apache.lucene.util.CharsRef,%20boolean%29)).  This behavior can cause problems for PhraseQueries and the like, see first **Note** on the `SynonymFilter` docs.

If you are using the same `Analyzer` for querying and indexing, then both queries and docs written to the index will, of course, be treated the same way.  `SynonymFilter` with `keepOrig` set to true is one of the few `Analyzers` that is reasonably often applied incongruously between querying and indexing, but that is entirely up to your implementation.

As far as how it is implemented, the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.java) is available to you.

Comment: How does it deal with multi synonym words?
like "New York" = "NY"
wal mart = wal-mart = walmart
because it does the filtering token by token. I don't know how it finds the multi word synonyms

Comment: Is there something you are confused about on it's behavior, or do you want to know how the implementation handles the stream of tokens?  If the latter, that's why I provided the link to the source code.  If the former, it greedily searches for longest match it can from the given position (that is, if you have rules `foo` -> `bar`, `foo bar` -> `foobar`, then `foo bar` will become `foobar`, not `bar bar`).  I don't believe it supports things like `wal mart = wal-mart = walmart` (synonym rules have one input and one output). If there is something particular you want to ask about it, go ahead.

Comment: My question is how it handles the stream of token? because I guess synonym filter gets token one by one and it is state-less. For example if the current token is "New", how does it check the next token to see if it is "York" or not?

Comment: Great, if you want to know the implementation details of how it does what it does, [the source is there for you](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.0.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.java).

Comment: I read the code. I don't get what it does exactly. (I am not familiar with lucene and its structure.) 
For example I dont know if lucene uses SynonymFilter like other filters? right after lets say StopFilter?